# PHP7.3 on eregi

Tags: php, eregi

Already i try preg_match

`if (is_file("$Path/$file") && eregi("$Filter", $file))`

on

`if (is_file("$Path/$file") && preg_match("$Filter", $file))`

My Problem no output zip files.

#

**Original code**

#

```
<?php
    function getDirArray($Path="./",$Filter=".*",$Sorted="True")
        {
                $handle=opendir($Path);
                while ($file = readdir($handle))
                    {
                        if (is_file("$Path/$file") && eregi("$Filter", $file))
                            {
                                $dirArray[] = $file;
                            }
                    }
                closedir($handle);
                if (!is_array($dirArray))
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                if (strcasecmp($Sorted,"True"))
                    {
                        shuffle($dirArray);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        sort($dirArray);
                    }
                return $dirArray;
        }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, What is your problem. Please mention that

Comment: fixed. dhis is Correct      if (is_file("$Path/$file") && preg_match("/$Filter/i", $file))